# Azure Key Vault Linked service not working, debug failed, trigger success

Tags: pipeline, azure-keyvault, azure-data-factory

I have created a Linked Service using key vault and then used that Linked service in Data Linked Service (Azure SQL database). Both Linked services independently tested successfully. I have used that in a very simple pipeline, while I am debugging the pipeline, it gets failed with an error:

> 'Invalid linked service reference. Name: '.

This is referring to Key Vault linked service.

When I trigger the pipeline, it works fine. I have published my changes so many time but no success.

So my basic query is - My pipeline is not working on Debug, however it is working fine with Trigger now.

Comment: Welacome to Stack Overflow. Your question lacks details. Please, consider reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very strange thing I have noticed in Linked Service in ADF. I have selected Azure Key Vault near to password and just passed AKV linked service name there and it worked.

That suggests that JSON is not properly working with Azure key vault services in Linked Services. Well, my issue has been resolved however logically I am still unclear.

If any one looking for resolution of same, please refer below. Thank you.

[Key Vault Linked Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmNRx.png)

Answer (score 1):

When a pipeline is working by trigger, but not by debug, that suggests either:  there is a difference between the published version and the version in the UI, or, you have parameters that depend upon the trigger.

Comment: Thanks Martin, is there any way I can verify it ?
As I had published my Pipeline so many times but no luck...

Answer (score 1):

I had faced exactly the same problem, I performed the following actions:

1. Save all existing pipelines
2. Validated all
3. Publish all
4. Closed the datafactory browser window/tab
5. logged back into datafactory
6. Opened the pipeline again and the debug worked fine. I didn't have to touch the Azure Vault configuration. Its most likely to do with cached vault configuration (or a sync issue with the cached vault config)

Comment: What worked for me was to clear my local storage.